# How do I build my R package such that I can quickly adjust some style changes (e.g. main colors/font size)

Tags: r, design-patterns, r-package

I am working on my own R package. I am at the point where I want to write some functions that will visualise my data. I want to be able to quickly adjust the style of all my functions when I'm not happy with some configurations. Examples of this will be:

- Font size
- Primary/secondary colors
- Green/Orange/Red colors

Because, suppose I have `graphs.R`:

```
graph_a <- function(font_size = 9, primary_color = "#ffffff") { ... }

graph_b <- function(font_size = 9, primary_color = "#ffffff") { ... }

graph_c <- function(font_size = 9, primary_color = "#ffffff") { ... }
```

It would be a hassle to change all the pre-defined values if I want to increase my font size a bit. I was thinking of using a global constant, but cannot find anything on this on Google, and using a config file seems not the proper tactic as well. The first thing that comes to mind is add the following at the first line of `graphs.R`:

```
FONT_SIZE <- 9
PRIMARY_COLOR <- "#ffffff"
```

But what if I want to use these across my package?

Comment: You could use `options`.

Comment: @Roland could you elaborate? I've read in [this book on creating R packages](https://r-pkgs.org/r.html#code-r-landscape) that the `options` is something that should be "used with caution". That's one of the reasons why I haven't read that much into it.

Comment: You should read further down. I don't see how the solution proposed in the answer is inherently less problematic than using package `options`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define global variables in your package, they'll be available to all of the functions in the package, not just the ones in the same source file.  So that's not an issue.  (Though if the value of one constant depends on others, you have to take into account the order in which the source files are processed.  This can be controlled by the `Collate:` field in `DESCRIPTION`.)

A disadvantage of using global variables as you did is that it's difficult for a user to change them.  Once a package is installed, those values will be locked.  (It's still possible to change them by unlocking and replacing, but that's not easy.)

One approach that is fairly convenient is to have an environment to hold your style settings, and optionally functions to set and get them.  For example, your code might look like this:

```
defaultStyle <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
defaultStyle$FONT_SIZE <- 9
defaultStyle$PRIMARY_COLOR <- "#ffffff"

graph_a <- function(font_size = style$FONT_SIZE, 
                    primary_color = style$PRIMARY_COLOR,
                    style = defaultStyle) { ... }
```

Then a user could create an entirely different style and drop it in with one argument, e.g.

```
graph_a(style = my_style)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to be exactly something that I'm looking for. I really did not want to be using global variables, since that's a big no as far as my current experience goes.

Comment: I have a follow-up question on this. If a user provides a custom style `my_style` and only wants to change the `font_size` but use all the other default options. What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: I suggested an environment, but you could also use a list.  The main difference in this context is that lists are passed by value, environments are passed by reference.  With a list they could say `my_style <- defaultStyle; my_style$FONT_SIZE = 42`.  If they did that with the example I posted, they'd change the default.